# Redirect From one app page to another

Tags: development, 2013, sharepoint-addin, redirect

I am creating a Provider hosted app. In that I have created two different `.aspx` pages. I want to redirect to the other page. But I am not able to find it out how to redirect.

When I check my AppManifest file there is a URL to show which page to be load on start up. It is like follow.

```
<Properties>
    <Title>PollAppDemo1</Title>
    <StartPage>~remoteAppUrl/Pages/PollQuestionView.aspx?{StandardTokens}</StartPage>
</Properties>
```

I tried to put url like this in `Page.Response.Redirect("");` but m not able to do this.

Comment: I am putting Redirecting code to code behind on a Button click

Comment: I mean to say I have tried to put the url "~remoteAppUrl/Pages/PollQuestionView.aspx?{StandardTokens}" like this but it is not helping, In other page I have to pass the Query string with standard tokens.

Comment: I have to pass url in this format "/Pages/PollQuestionView.aspx?SPHostUrl=http%3a%2f%2fspmain%3a3865&SPLanguage=en-US&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=15.0.4420.1017" but it how to put this tokens in url and where to get those tokens that i don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Response.Redirect(TokenHelper.GetAppContextTokenRequestUrl(sharePointHostUrl, Server.UrlEncode(targetUrl)));
```

[The app redirect page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179932.aspx#Redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a server relative Url?

Like: `Page.Response.Redirect("PollQuestionView.aspx")`

The standard tokens are replaced at compilation time in for example the AppManifest. They will **NOT** be replaced in your code at runtime. So if you want to pass them on you would need to get them from `Page.Request` and add them to the Redirect Url.

Use `Page.Request.Querystring["Name of parameter"]` to get the value of a specific querystring parameter.

Comment: no its not working. I'll need the standard tokens with my url otherwise it wont work.

Comment: Yes you are write. But how could I get these tokens from `Page.Request`??

Comment: I want url like _/Pages/PollQuestionView.aspx?SPHostUrl=http%3a%2f%2fspmain%3a3865&SPLanguage=en-US&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=15.0.4420.1017_

Comment: Updated with how to retreive from querystring

Comment: @RahulGokani you can use Request.Url.Query to get query string back.

Comment: I want to Redirect from one page to another page and in that I have to pass tokens on time of redirecting It means I want to pass tokens from `Page.Response.Redirect("PollQuestionView.aspx?{Tokens}")` For that I am finding the way to get Tokens...

Answer (score 0):

<del>Use this instead,

    string url = "~remoteAppUrl/Pages/PollQuestionView.aspx";

    string queryString = "SPHostUrl=http%3a%2f%2fspmain%3a3865&SPLanguage=en??-US&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=15.0.4420.1017";

    SPUtility.Redirect(url, SPRedirectFlags.Default, Context, queryString);


[How to use SPUtility.Redirect][1]

[MSDN reference][2]</del>

This should work,

```
Response.Redirect(TokenHelper.GetAppContextTokenRequestUrl(sharePointHostUrl, Server.UrlEncode(targetUrl)));
```

Comment: In SharePoint App Development I cant use SPUtility. I have to use Client Context Model to develop this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the current SharePointContext instance instead of redirecting back to the SharePoint host and then being redirected once again to the app to get a new context (as suggested by Rahul).

Add these utility methods to the auto-generated SharePointContext.cs file (at around line 277 which is where the SharePointContext class definition ends. Don't forget to add 'using System.Linq;' and 'using System.Collections.Specialized;')

```
public void AddStandardTokensToQueryString(NameValueCollection queryString)
{
    if (queryString == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("queryString");
    }

    if (spHostUrl != null)
    {
        queryString[SPHostUrlKey] = SPHostUrl.AbsoluteUri;
    }

    if (spAppWebUrl != null)
    {
        queryString[SPAppWebUrlKey] = SPAppWebUrl.AbsoluteUri;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SPLanguage))
    {
        queryString[SPLanguageKey] = SPLanguage;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SPClientTag))
    {
        queryString[SPClientTagKey] = SPClientTag;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SPProductNumber))
    {
        queryString[SPProductNumberKey] = SPProductNumber;
    }
}
public String GetStandardTokensQueryStringValue()
{
    NameValueCollection qs = new NameValueCollection();
    AddStandardTokensToQueryString(qs);
    return String.Join("&",
        qs.AllKeys.Select(a => a + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(qs[a])));
}
```

How to use:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SharePointContext spContext = 
        SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);
    Response.Redirect("PollQuestionView.aspx?" + 
        spContext.GetStandardTokensQueryStringValue(), true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use window.location.href = url; for sharepointhosted App and Client API.

Comment: It would be great if you add some more explanation to your answer. It will be good in reading and understanding.